# Creating QTextTable And Inserting Data

Tags: c++, qt, qtextcursor

I am trying to create a QTextTable and insert data into it. Currently I am unable to create the table because of several errors

> use of undeclared identifier 'editor'

I am also unsure how I can insert data into the TextTable. My code is below

```
QTextCursor cursor(editor->textCursor());
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);
QTextTable *table = cursor.insertTable(5, 3);
```

I tried the code below and I have no error I am just wondering how i can insert data into the texttable so i can print it?

```
QTextEdit *editor = new QTextEdit();
QTextCursor cursor(editor->textCursor());
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);
QTextTable *table = cursor.insertTable(5, 3);
table->insertRows(0, 5);
```

Comment: Where did you declare `editor` ?

Comment: I have not, i copied this code from the Qt docs

Comment: You have to declare your variable `editor` with something like `QTextEdit *editor = new QTextEdit();`. I'm not used to QT but your question doesn't contain the declaration of `editor` which seems to be the problem.

Comment: I tried that but do you know how i can insert data to the table so i can print it?

Comment: As I said, I'm not used to qt, thus I'm not able to help you for this. At least you don't have error anymore.

Comment: Copying things without understanding and expecting them to work is known by a rather derogatory term: cargo cult software development. The term is derogatory for a good reason: it's a really bad practice. You need to understand what you're doing. Assuming that you understand how C++ works, all you need to do is to read the documentation that comes with Qt for the classes you intend to use. At this point, it looks like you're trying to use Qt without quite knowing C++. Perhaps you should work towards bettering your C++ in parallel with your Qt endeavors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a text browser and try this one. (The form contains a `QTextBrowser` with object name `textBrowser`)

```
QTextCursor cursor(ui->textBrowser->textCursor());
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);

QTextTable *table = cursor.insertTable(2, 3);

for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {

        table->cellAt(i, j).firstCursorPosition().insertText("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I can print the QTextTable now since it is in a QTextBrowser? I have set up a QPrinter and a QPainter

Comment: `QTextBrowser` comes with a method called `print` which accepts a `QPrinter` reference. You can try this.

`QPrinter printer;
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setOutputFileName("textBrowser.pdf");
ui->textBrowser->print(&printer);`